# What can be considered an instance in VB.NET: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, oop, list, constructor, instance

I'm stuck with the following problem. I have a class with a constructor (a `New(<args>)` method). I also have a `List` of objects of this class that I'd like to populate. To give an example, here's some toy code (avoiding properties and such):

```
Class Thing
    Public PositionX, PositionY As UInteger
    Public Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, _
                   ByVal positionX As UInteger, _
                   ByVal positionY As UInteger)
        Me.PositionX = positionX
        Me.PositionY = positionY
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also, elsewhere in code I'm declaring a list of `Thing`s:

```
Dim things As List(Of Thing)
```

When trying to run the following line of code, `things.Add(New Thing("some name', 1, 1))`, I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception. Clearly, I have a misunderstanding of what an instance of an object really is and how VB.NET goes about working with them. I guess it goes back to my C/C++ background.

<strike>Of course, I could initialize a variable with the `New` constructor, and *then* add it to the list:</strike>

The following does not work either:

```
Dim myThing = New Thing("some name", 1, 1)
things.Add(myThing)
```

My question is why does simply saying `New Thing("some name', 1, 1)` does not create an *instance* of `Thing` what what is the right way to think about such things? Anything I'm doing wrong by design?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you just need to instance your list:

```
Dim things As New List(Of Thing)
```

I think everything is fine with the handling of the `thing` class, but the list needs an instance too - Its a class/instance just like the things are.

Comment: OMG! I feel quite silly now = ) Thanks! (Will accept the answer after the required 10 minutes of so)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
Dim things as New List(Of Thing)
```

or:

```
Dim things as List(Of Thing)
things=New List(Of Thing)
```